# Model test case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model for which I am writing a test case. I have loaded the data in fixture as well, but when I am testing child object is equal to child, I get the following error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `commvib' for #<CommvibTest:0x00000009b2cc68> ].
```

My class is called `CommVib`, and the code for my testing is

```
test "relationship test" do
  assert_equal(Comm.find(6) == commvib.Comm.find(6))
end
```

where `CommVib` is having a `belongs_to` relationship with `Comm` class.

Comment: Where do you define `commvib`?

Comment: CommVib and Comm both are model class

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand you correctly, you should change your code to

```
test "relationship test" do
  comm = Comm.find(6)
  assert_equal(comm == comm.commvib.comm, true)
end
```

I assume that Comm model has `has_one :commvib` association.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. First of all, the error message:

You get `undefined local variable or method 'commvib'` because Ruby doesn't know what `commvib` is meant to be, and neither do I. If you are trying to load a fixture, the syntax is probably

```
comm_vibs(:one)
```

assuming "comm_vibs" is the plural of "comm_vib" and you have a `one:` key in your fixture file.

Next up, your association:

If `CommVib` `belongs_to :comm`, you should reference it like

```
comm_vib.comm
```

That method returns the `Comm` object associated with `comm_vib` - there is no need to `find` it.

And finally, your assertion:

[`assert_equal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_equal) has this signature:

```
assert_equal(expected, actual, failure_message = nil)
```

So to use it you'd have to do something like `assert_equal(foo, bar)` - not `assert_equal(foo == bar)`.

All in all, your code should probably look like this in the end:

```
assert_equal Comm.find(6), comm_vibs(:one).comm
```